# Oxidation of polycyclic aromatic compounds using KMnO4

Tags: aromatic-compounds, organic-oxidation

How is [tetracene](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetracene) oxidised by $\ce{KMnO4}?$ It appears that the product is a white solid with a benzene ring inside.

What is the reaction mechanism? Is it radical based? Or does the $\ce{MnO4-}$ ion react with tetracene in a similar manner as alkenes are hydroxylated to diols?

Do I have to consider the inherent aromaticity of tetracene to deduce which "double bond" (because there's no "true" double bond) the $\ce{MnO4-}$ species reacts with?

Comment: My money is on either phthalic acid or the 1,2,4,5-tetracarboxylic acid.

Comment: I'm guessing quinone will be at least intermediate.

Comment: @Jan Sounds reasonable, since naphthalene is oxidized to phthalic acid under these conditions.